# Fresh Raspberry Pi with Ethernet only. How To?

Tags: linux

I'm already spent a 2 hours for such How-To.

I'm looking for instruction how to setup anything, actually Linux(Ubuntu/Debian) from my Host(Ubuntu) to my Fresh Raspberry Pi. I've bought it just a couple hours ago.

Is there way to setup Debian Net-Installer on my Ubuntu via dhcpd to ETH->To->Pi ?

I have no any card writer/reader. I have only fresh RPi & 8 GB new flash memory sd card into it.

Comment: you should get yourself a card reader, you cannot do anything unless you can write a system image to the SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi requires an SD card with an OS image to boot.

You MUST write the OS to the card from another computer with an SD card writer.

If you don't have a writer, you can buy an SD card with the OS already written to it.

Comment: here is an example of a [preinstalled SD card](http://swag.raspberrypi.org/collections/frontpage/products/noobs-8gb-sd-card) you can purchase.

Comment: Are you sure? I think, there is must be a way to setup Debian via just an Ethernet.

Comment: there is, but the pi is built to boot from the sd card only.

Comment: Very very bad. Without SD card writer - I can't do anything. There is no any bios sub-system on the RaPi board, Am I right? I'm trying to boot with hdmi monitor, mouse and keyboard, ethernet and fresh sd-card. Monitor - is black...

Comment: Correct.  What little firmware that exists on it does nothing more than start booting from the sdcard.